# Is there a compilation of standard building blocks for comments?

Tags: support, comments, new-users

On http://tex.stackexchange.com there is a [compilation of standard text building blocks](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/430/text-building-blocks?lq=1) that can be used to comment frequently appearing types of questions or answers. Those are typically of a kind that they are close to or slightly across the border of what we would ideally expect as good sx.com questions or answers, cf. questions where the intention is not quite clear or that are a bit too localized but could be easily edited to make it a reasonable question.

I tried to find something similar here but couldn't find anything. Did I search for the wrong search terms or does such a compilation not exist yet over here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, we do not have a standard compilation of such things. Putting one together would be nice.

I use the [AutoReviewComments](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) extension, which automatically adds "Welcome to Bicycles!" when replying to a new user.

For a starter, here's my set of automatic comments that I actually use:
(`[A]` is comments on Answers, `[Q]` is comments on questions, `$SITEURL$` gets automatically changed to `http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/`)

```
###[A] Nothing but a URL (and isn't spam)
While this may theoretically answer the question,
[it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include 
the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

###[A] Comment as answer
This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, 
[you will be able to post comments](http://$SITEURL$/privileges/comment).
For the moment I've migrated this to a comment for you.

###[A] Not an answer
Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers.
This doesn't seem to answer the question in any way.

###[A] Needs more detail
We're looking for answers with **more detail**.
Please give us some *reasons* and *explanation*, **not just a one-line answer**.
A short answer like this with no explanation is likely to be deleted.

###[Q] Insufficient Detail
We really need more information to give you a good answer. 
Could you be more specific?
Perhaps consider including some pictures, both of the overall bike and the specific areas?
Vague questions without enough detail to be answerable are likely to be removed.

###[Q] Pictures, Pictures, Pictures!
**Pictures, Pictures, Pictures!**
For most mechanical problems, it can be very helpful to include detailed 
pictures of the problem areas from multiple angles, and possibly also an 
overall shot of the bike.

###[Q] Q&A is hard, let's go shopping!
It's best if your question is more about how to look for what you want,
rather than looking for specific product recommendations.
Specific product recommendations can be problematic because not all products
are available in all areas and products change year to year. 
See also: [Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).
```

Comment: Your compilation looks indeed like a nice point to start from. Also thanks for the link to the AutoReviewComment script. I didn't know that and it looks like it could save some work.